# How do I run a PAR packed file in Windows Vista or Windows 7 running with higher privileges?

Tags: perl, windows-vista, manifest, par, packer

Does anyone know how to make a [PAR](http://par.perl.org) packed Perl application run with higher privileges?
I've read that there must be somewhere some kind of manifest file, but how should this file look like and how to combine it with the PAR packed executable? This is still unknown to me.

Any ideas?

Comment: I reposted your question to the [PAR mailing list](http://lists.perl.org/list/par.html).

Answer (score 0):

In http://www.mail-archive.com/par@perl.org/msg04642.html Mark Dootson proposed a possible implementation of UAC manifests for pp-packed executables using Win32::Exe:PP.

Until that is done, though, there is an easy workaround, which you probably already knew: Name the .exe file "setup.exe" and the user will be prompted for elevated rights. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I know.
Please see this http://codepad.org/CDWhFoZu

my $ exe = Win32 :: Exe-> new ('C: \ Users \ treeboa \ perl \ pic.exe');
Specifies the exe that want to run in administrator

$ Exe-> update (manifest => '. / Pic.exe.manifest');
I set to pic.exe the pic.exe.manifest

Run the update.pl

Double-click the pic.exe
Run dialog displays the administrator pic.exe

Success!